# Need facebook like button without count

Tags: facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook Like-Button - hide count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950172/facebook-like-button-hide-count)

I need facebook like button without count information. I tried it with giving 50px width. but when someone "like" the page its turn in "you liked it" and distorting the UI.

I need just like image without counr.

Thanks
Suren

Comment: If you are in iframe mode this is possible by just reducing the width to about 50px. But XFBML or HTML5 mode will not obey your width.

Comment: Check out http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/2950172/facebook-like-button-hide-count

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you wrap it in div containers w/ absolute dimensions & float it. . . so the overflow wont disrupt anything.

Comment: This solution is out of date now. You can still do it though, see this blog post: http://jacobquatier.com/posts/2013/04/01/facebook-like-buttons-without-count/

Comment: Yes, but it's forbidden by [fb policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) ;)
IV. Application Integration Points 4 d. You must not obscure or cover elements of our social plugins, such as the Like button or Like box plugin.

Answer (score 5):

Just give a width of 47px and it seems to works fine. I think they have changed the UI recently - now when you like it there is just a tickbox added to the like button and it doesn't distort the UI.

Comment: I am using 50px and it is doing good the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

NB. Facebook localizes the button - so the "like" button might be in a different language. Then of course this image is not a standard width - so you cant guarantee being able to hide it by setting width of iframe or css settings.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible. The whole UI is driven from Facebook and you can see all the variations here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

However, if you want, you may apply some CSS/JavaScript hack. The count is under `uiGrid` class, you may target this element and set display none after the page has rendered. In JQuery, you would `$('.uiGrid').hide()`

But the suggestion above is not recommended.

Comment: I don't think you could do that, as the Like button is inside an iFrame controlled by Facebook...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a question with several much more detailed answers to the different ways of doing this:
http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/2950172/facebook-like-button-hide-count

There are apparently a few cases where the answer is slightly different -- one for the javascript version, one with the iframe version, etc.