# How to show full number of likes near facebook like button with "button_count" layout

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

Facebook like button with "button_count" layout shows rounded number e.g 13K.

[image]

The current standard also shows something else. How to show full number of likes?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the "standard" layout instead of "button count"

This should give you the style as shown in the first example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950172/facebook-like-button-hide-count)