# Hide Facebook Like Button Count But Allow Comments

Tags: facebook, button, hide, facebook-like, counter

Is it possible to hide the counter on the Facebook Like button without hiding the comments box that pops up?  This older thread seems to allude to being able to do so but none of the example I tried here allow the comments to appear.

[Facebook Like-Button - hide count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950172/facebook-like-button-hide-count)

Suggestion: Before posting a solution, test it.  And if it works, post not just the CSS but also an example of the HTML.

Thanks!

Comment: I think this URL will be of help:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950172/facebook-like-button-hide-count][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950172/facebook-like-button-hide-count

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=facebook+like+button+site:userscripts.org

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the Like button, there is a dialog that will do the feed posting

See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>My Feed Dialog Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='fb-root'></div>
    <script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
    <p><a onclick='postToFeed(); return false;'>Post to Feed</a></p>
    <p id='msg'></p>

    <script> 
      FB.init({appId: "YOUR_APP_ID", status: true, cookie: true});

      function postToFeed() {

        // calling the API ...
        var obj = {
          method: 'feed',
          link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
          picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
          name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
          caption: 'Reference Documentation',
          description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
        };

        function callback(response) {
          document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
        }

        FB.ui(obj, callback);
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

*Note that the above example assumes that the user is already logged in and has authorized your application*