# Facebook like button: remove the initial message

Tags: facebook-like

I'm using the [like button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) from Facebook...(it seems to have changed many times over the p ast two years so I am talking about the most recent version).

Is there a way to not show the initial message which says,
"Be the first of your friends to like this"

I would like to have just the button and count (and keep the count empty if no one has liked it yet.

Comment: This has been discussed pretty extensively over here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950172/facebook-like-button-hide-count

Comment: I looked at that but now there is no iframe code anymore...it's javascript with a div that pulls in the facebook button...

Comment: use different layout style? like `button_count` or `box_count`