# Facebook Like Hide Count Using New Div Method

Tags: facebook-like, counter

I am unable to comment on a previous topic: [Facebook Like-Button - hide count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950172/facebook-like-button-hide-count)

So I am posting a new question:

What is the optimum method to hide the facebook like count when using the new method of placing the script and div as shown here? :

namespace

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# video: http://ogp.me/ns/video#">
```

markup

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=APP ID NUMBER";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

with

`<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://domain.com" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false" data-font="arial"></div>`

Since many of the previous solutions use a div and overflow hidden to obscure the count, I'm also interested to know how hiding the count might be achieved taking into account any language localisations for the word "like", such that the word like in a given language is not obscured.