# how to hide send button from like button of facebook but don't hide add comment and send to facebook frame

Tags: javascript, css, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

i'm developing a page with like button added like this:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
  ...

<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/it_IT/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=my_app_id";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

...

<div id="facebook" style="float:right;">
    <fb:like href="my_link_to_share" send="true" width="20" show_faces="true" font="verdana">
    </fb:like>
</div>
```

normally it will be:

[image]

i correctly hide the text and send button in this way:

```
div#facebook{
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 5px;
    width: 80px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

but when i click like button it should appear:

[image]

but since i put `width:80px`, comment and share box will take that width. is possible to hide send button and text but maintain the size of box? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really just want the send button to be hidden (not the like count), than just uncheck "Send Button" and change Layout to "button count" on the like button create page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: ok.. really better.. but is not possible to hide count of like?

Comment: There are some methods mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950172/facebook-like-button-hide-count but most of these are old and don't work anymore due to the new dialog window. The proposed solutions are hacky at best.